# Removing index in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

When creating a table I added this index mistakenly:

```
add_index :progresses, [:user_id, :lesson_id], unique: true
```

How would I go about removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very similar way:

```
remove_index :progresses, [:user_id, :lesson_id]
```

or, you can rollback migration creating your table with:

```
rake db:rollback
```

then correct your migration file (removing `add_index` line) and run migration again.